# C# XML - Help creating new tag with an ID?

Tags: c#, xml

I wish to create a file somewhat like this: http://pastebin.com/89kuK8h2

There is a  tag, and in this example I got from MSDN, the customer tag also has a value and still ends in <\Customer>:

Customer CustomerID="HELLO"> // <---- This Line

I want to know how to do that

Currently I am creating tags like:

```
XmlNode xHeader = xDoc.CreateElement("Customer");
```

and appending like this:

```
xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xHeader);
            xHeader.AppendChild(xCustomerID);
```

Answer (score 0):

`XDocument` may be a way forward here, as its API is much simpler:

```
var root = new XDocument("Root", 
     new XElement("Customers"),
        new XElement("Customer",
           new XAttribute("CustomerID", "HELLO"),
           new XElement("CompanyName", this.CompanyName),
           new XElement("ContactName", this.ContactName),
           new XElement("ContactTitle", this.ContactTitle),
           new XElement("Phone", this.Phone),
           new XElement("FullAddress", 
              new XElement("Address", "..."),
              new XElement("Region", "...")

           )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use LINQ to XML. It's easy to build your xml:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
        new XElement("Customers",
            new XElement("Customer",
                new XAttribute("CustomerID", "HELLO"),
                new XElement("CompanyName", "Great Lakes Food Market"),
                new XElement("ContactName", "Howard Snyder"),
                new XElement("ContactTitle", "Marketing Managerr"),
                new XElement("Phone", "(503) 555-7555"),
                new XElement("FullAddress",
                    new XElement("Address", "2732 Baker Blvd."),
                    new XElement("City", "Eugene"),
                    new XElement("Region", "OR")
                    new XElement("PostalCode", "97403")
                    new XElement("Country", "USA")
                    )
                )
        )));
```

Suggested reading: [Creating XML Trees in C# (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx)